# Erro ao invocar a impressão de um mapa em vba V9

Tags: vba

Boa tarde,

preciso de ajuda a invocar em runtime a impressão de um Mapa baseados no GCPVLS70, que usa a Tabela “DESCVIAS”:

Ao usar:

```
Aplicacao.PlataformaPRIMAVERA.Mapas.ImprimeListagem tSeries!Config, "Documento de Venda", "W", 1
```

Dá o Erro:

A tabela 'DescVias' não foi localizada.
Erro no arquivo LS-ORC P {D4C75E32-84CC-4314-9C1C-A0602CD78744}.rpt:
a tabela não foi localizada.

Como resolver ? Agradeço ajuda, p.f.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, penso que esse problema pode ter a ver com o facto de existirem tabelas no mapa que não estão localizadas. Deves editar o mapa com crystal reports e fazer a respetiva localição.
Sendo um mapa de vendas, podes também experimentar com este método:

```
BSO.Comercial.Vendas.ImprimeDocumento TipoDoc, Serie, NumDoc, Filial
```

Comment: Bom dia, a tabela 'DescVias' tem de ser "Alimentada" por código nada tem a ver com o Crystal Reports

Comment: Qual é o nome do mapa?

Comment: O mapa é LS-ORC P.rpt

Comment: Verifica se o mapa tem a tal tabela DescVias. É uma tabela temporária e está mesmo a dar erro, por não estar localizada. Mas ela deve vir localizada de base, deves colocar um ticket para resolver isso. Experimenta uma impressão com o mapa de vendas GCPVLS70, também te deve dar o mesmo erro.

Comment: O mapa tem a tabela, o problema está em "alimentá-la". Em qualquer outro mapa de base funciona corretamente, menos no "corrido". Em impressão no ERP este mapa funciona, portanto o problema está no vba...

Comment: Sim, eu testei e também me ocorre o mesmo erro, deves portanto colocar um ticket para que isso possa ser corrigido.

Comment: Mas então este erro não devia também acontecer quando se imprime um documento no ERP?